# How to display output of two table SQLite query in ListView (android)

Tags: android, database, android-listview

I am learning Android. I am trying to learn SQLite database but I am getting problem in that. I am unable to read the output of Cursor and display it in ListView. Here is my TestAdapter.java code-

```
public class TestAdapter  
{ 
    protected static final String TAG = "DataAdapter"; 

    private final Context mContext; 
    private SQLiteDatabase mDb; 
    private DataBaseHelper mDbHelper; 
    public static final String COL_ID = "_id";
    public static String F_name = "F_name";
    public static String F_price = "F_price";
    public static String R_name = "R_name";

    public TestAdapter(Context context)  
    { 
        this.mContext = context; 
        mDbHelper = new DataBaseHelper(mContext); 
    } 

    public TestAdapter createDatabase() throws SQLException  
    { 
        try  
        { 
            mDbHelper.createDataBase(); 
        }  
        catch (IOException mIOException)  
        { 
            Log.e(TAG, mIOException.toString() + "  UnableToCreateDatabase"); 
            throw new Error("UnableToCreateDatabase"); 
        } 
        return this; 
    } 

    public TestAdapter open() throws SQLException  
    { 
        try  
        { 
            mDbHelper.openDataBase(); 
            mDbHelper.close(); 
            mDb = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase(); 
        }  
        catch (SQLException mSQLException)  
        { 
            Log.e(TAG, "open >>"+ mSQLException.toString()); 
            throw mSQLException; 
        } 
        return this; 
    } 

    public void close()  
    { 
        mDbHelper.close(); 
    } 

     public Cursor getTestData() 
     { 
         try 
         { 
             String sql ="select Food.F_name,Food.F_price,R.R_name from Food inner join R on Food.r_id=R.R_id"; 

             Cursor mCur = mDb.rawQuery(sql, null); 
             if (mCur!=null) 
             { 
                 F_name =mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("F_name"));
                 F_price =mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("F_price"));
                 R_name =mCur.getString(mCur.getColumnIndex("F_name"));
                mCur.moveToNext(); 
             } 
             return mCur; 
         } 
         catch (SQLException mSQLException)  
         { 
             Log.e(TAG, "getTestData >>"+ mSQLException.toString()); 
             throw mSQLException; 
         } 
     }



    public boolean SaveEmployee(String name, String email) 
    {
        try
        {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("Name", name);
            cv.put("Email", email);

            mDb.insert("Employees", null, cv);

            Log.d("SaveEmployee", "informationsaved");
            return true;

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Log.d("SaveEmployee", ex.toString());
            return false;
        }
    }


}
```

here main activity

```
    public class CustomDataList extends ListActivity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    TestAdapter dbHelper = new TestAdapter(this);
    dbHelper.open();

    // Get a Cursor for the list items
    Cursor listCursor = dbHelper.getTestData();
    startManagingCursor(listCursor);

    // set the custom list adapter
    setListAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, listCursor));
}

private class MyListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_item_with_description, cursor);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        TextView title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        title.setText(cursor.getString(
                    cursor.getColumnIndex(TestAdapter.F_name)));

        TextView details = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_details);
        StringBuffer detailsText = new StringBuffer();

        int price = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(TestAdapter.F_price));
        if (price > 0){
            detailsText.append("$"+price+".00");
        } else {
            detailsText.append("Price Unavailable");
        }
        String description = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(
                TestAdapter.R_name));
        if (description != null && description.length() > 0){
            detailsText.append(", "+description);
        }
        details.setText(detailsText.toString());

    }

}
```

}

its not working.. any one please help. .. i just want to show the query data on a list view

Answer (score 0):

Try cursorAdapter

```
class MyListAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


    public MyListAdapter (Context context, Cursor c) {
        super(context, c);
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        String id = cursor.getString(0);
        String name = cursor.getString(1);
        // Get all the values
        // Use it however you need to

    }

    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        // Inflate your view here.

    }
}
```

Comment: i am not familiar with cursor adapter.. can u gv me this type of example link :)

Comment: http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2012/08/22/android-list-view-from-database-with-cursor-adapter/